# Convert a list of string (that contain a space separator in the begging to show depth of the word in the dict ) to a nested dict python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

> I have a problem when i want to convert a list of string with
>   undefined depth with space indicated the depth of that string in the
>   dict i will show as more examples to my problem:

**i want to have this structure into a dict from a list :**

[image: enter image description here[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aILa.png)

***the input list :***

```
['[id]', '[first_name]', '[last_name]', '[addresses]', '  [[status]]', '  [[address]]', '  [[city]]', '  [[state]]', '  [[zip]]', '  [[numberOfYears]]', '    [[[status]]]', '      [[[[SUM]]]]', '        [[[[[SUBSUM]]]]]']
```

***the expected output:***

```
[
{
  "name": "[id]",
  "fields": []
},
{
  "name": "[firstname]",
  "fields":[]
},
{
  "name": "[lastname]",
  "fields": []
},
{
  "name": "[adresses]",
  "fields":{
    "name": "[status]",
    "fields": []
  }
},
{
  "name": "[address]",
  "fields": []
},
{
  "name": "[city]",
  "fields": []
},
{
  "name": "[state]",
  "fields":[]
},
{
  "name": "[zip]",
  "fields": []
},{
  "name": "[numberOfYears]",
  "fields":[{
    " name": "[status]",
    "fields": [{"name":"[SUM]",
    "fields":[{"name":"[SUBSUM]","fields":{}}]}]}

  ] }]
```

Comment: you showed your question, whats the problem?

Comment: i want to get the given dict form the input list @Nullman

Comment: That's what you *want*. What is your problem with writing code for this?

Comment: yes, i got that, but whats the problem? you've tried something and it isn't working?

Comment: yes i can't add data to the dict when the depth is grater then 1

Comment: @Nullman i tried a script that show only a list of the  first depth element something like this : [{'fields': [], 'name': '[id]'}, {'fields': [], 'name': '[first_name]'}, {'fields': [], 'name': '[last_name]'}]

Answer (score 1):

You will need some kind of a tree structure. As this is rather common, genious minds have mad libraries available that hides the complexity, e.g. [**`anytree`**](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from anytree import AnyNode, RenderTree
from anytree.exporter import JsonExporter

data = """
[id]
[first_name]
[last_name]
[addresses]
  [[status]]
  [[address]]
  [[city]]
  [[state]]
  [[zip]]
  [[numberOfYears]]
    [[[status]]]
      [[[[SUM]]]]
        [[[[[SUBSUM]]]]]
"""

parent, oldws = None, None

root = AnyNode(name="root")
for line in data.split("\n"):
    if line:
        ws = len(line) - len(line.lstrip(' '))
        word = line.lstrip().strip("[]")

        if not oldws:
            oldws = ws

        if ws == 0:
            parent = AnyNode(name=word, parent=root)
        elif oldws < ws:
            parent = AnyNode(name=word, parent=parent)
        else:
            node = AnyNode(name=word, parent=parent)

        oldws = ws

print(RenderTree(root))
```

Which yields

```
AnyNode(name='root')
├── AnyNode(name='id')
├── AnyNode(name='first_name')
├── AnyNode(name='last_name')
└── AnyNode(name='addresses')
    ├── AnyNode(name='status')
    ├── AnyNode(name='address')
    ├── AnyNode(name='city')
    ├── AnyNode(name='state')
    ├── AnyNode(name='zip')
    ├── AnyNode(name='numberOfYears')
    └── AnyNode(name='status')
        └── AnyNode(name='SUM')
            └── AnyNode(name='SUBSUM')
```

Now, the last step is to export it, see the [**vast documentation**](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporter.html) on how to do that.